# cordova get click event javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm a little bit confused about how cordova works (i'm using android)...i've got an html page with this button:

```
 <button id="mannaggia">mannaggia</button>
```

i'm trying to insert a javascript tag:

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("mannaggia").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

        myFunction(){

            alert('is anybody out there?');
            window.location="pag2.html";

        }

        </script>
```

nothing happens..
trying to insert a function in index.js outside this page is the same result...thank you

Answer (score 1):

The function is declared after you added the event listener, so myFunction was undefined. Try putting the function before you add listener.

Answer (score 1):

Revisit your html file once again.
best place to start your code are inside the device ready event

read more here [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use device APIs
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```